# Pandas' groupby().apply() method

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have following application on pandas' `groupby.apply` method

```
import pandas as pd
dat = pd.DataFrame({'name' : ['A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'], 'val' : [1,2,1,2,4]})
dat.groupby('name').apply(lambda x : x)
```

This gives result as

```
  name  val
0    A    1
1    C    2
2    A    1
3    B    2
4    C    4
```

However I wanted to get the dataframe corresponding to `i-th` group. For example, for the first group I intend to get dataframe with `name = 'A'` etc.

Is there any method available to achieve the same?

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly. Do you mean you want to split the dataframe up in *three* different dfs? I.e. get `df_A`, `df_B`, and `df_C`?

Comment: yes. However in this particular example, the grouping is based on only one column i.e. `name`. In my actual dataframe, it is a bit complex as there I am grouping based on multiple columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as follows:

```
# wrap groupby object in `list`, then in `dict`
groups = dict(list(dat.groupby('name')))

# all keys
print(groups.keys())
dict_keys(['A', 'B', 'C'])

# value for first key
print(groups['A'])

  name  val
0    A    1
2    A    1
```

Suppose you were grouping by `name` and `val`, then you might end up with awkard keys. E.g.:

```
groups = dict(list(dat.groupby(['name','val'])))

print(groups.keys())
dict_keys([('A', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 2), ('C', 4)])
```

In this case, you might consider using a dictionary comprehension, like this:

```
groups = {idx:group[1] for idx, group in enumerate(dat.groupby(['name','val']))}

print(groups.keys())
dict_keys([0, 1, 2, 3])

print(groups[0])

  name  val
0    A    1
2    A    1
```

More generally, if you want to customize processing any further, you can access the groups as follows:

```
for name, group in dat.groupby(['name','val']):
    print(name)
    print(group)
    break

('A', 1) # `name`, i.e. first grouper

# `group`, i.e. `df` belonging to the grouper
  name  val
0    A    1
2    A    1
```